# Send php string to javascript on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, redis

I want to send a php string to javascript script when I click on submit. I already know how to pass variable with `json_encode`:

```
var str1 = <?php echo json_encode($str) ?>;
```

What I want to know is, how to pass a variable which needs to be selected from a dynamic drop down list and which is in a `while` loop.

```
<section class="content">
   <form id="admin" action="monitor.php" method="GET">
    Servers :<br/>
    <select name="category" id="category">
<option value="select">Select...</option> 

<?php
$redis = new redis();

$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$result = $redis->keys('*');
$i = 0;

while ($result[$i]!=null) 
{
    $Addr[$i] = $redis->hget($result[$i], 'Address');
    $Port[$i] = $redis->hget($result[$i], 'Port');
    $fullAdr[$i] = sprintf ("%s:%s", $Addr[$i], $Port[$i]);
    $asdf[$i] = sprintf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $fullAdr[$i], $result[$i]);
    echo $asdf[$i];

    $i++;
}
?>
</select><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Now I can't use `var str1 = <?php echo json_encode($str) ?>;` because I don't know which selection would the user choose.

Each selection contains the IP of a server. I need that IP to pass to a Javascript script when I click on submit.

Comment: php can only direct talk to JS when the page is first generated. after that, php can NOT do anything, except in response to ajax requests from the client.

Comment: Let me paste more code. I do generate a new page when I click on submit. I get a new url which is the url containing the IP I need: http://localhost/test/monitor.php?category=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4561

Comment: @MarcB  I edited the pasted code, now you see that submit button has an action which generates a new url on the same page.

Comment: so submit the form, then php can generate your new script with that posted value in it. like I said: php cannot do ANYTHING with that page once it's reached the client. it can't see what you selected until the form is submitted and sent back to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering it for the future reference, if someone ever encounters the same problem.

I made it work by putting a php on top of the file:

```
<?php

$JSAddress = $_GET['servers'];

?>
```

Which I later passed to javascript with:

```
var str1 = <?php echo json_encode($JSAddress) ?>;
```

So basically when the user clicks on submit, it sends the request to the php above which stores the value and passes it to javascript.